# confused with async series control flow

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

i am new to nodejs.i want do two task in series.I use *async* module

```
var async = require('async');
async.series([
    function () {
        console.log("step 1");
    }, function () {
        console.log('step 2');
    }]);

console.log("end");
```

I expect the result is

```
step 1
step 2
end
```

but the result is

```
step 1
end
```

why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each function is asynchronous, so it is passed a callback. For it to progress to the next step, you need to call the callback.

```
var async = require('async');
async.series([
    function (callback) {
        console.log("step 1");
        callback();
    },
    function (callback) {
        console.log('step 2');
        callback();
    }
]);

console.log("end");
```

Note, that this will do what you want, but your `end` is still in a weird place. The series callbacks aren't actually asynchronous, so everything will run synchronously. If it were all running asynchronously, your end callback would run in the middle somewhere. Really, it should be in the end callback.

e.g.

```
var async = require('async');
async.series([
    function (callback) {
        console.log("step 1");
        setTimeout(callback, 100);
    },
    function (callback) {
        console.log('step 2');
        setTimeout(callback, 100);
    }
], function(err){
    console.log("end");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would you mind explaining further why you used `setTimeout`? Isn't `async.series` supposed to wait for each function to end already?

Comment: @JohnPoe It is just an example. The objective of `async.series` is to run a set of asynchronous functions after each previous one finishes. In this case I've added the setTimeout to make the function asynchronous, otherwise the example wouldn't need to use `async.series` at all.